# How to adjust max values without normalization in scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I need to prepare scatterplot using all values in data frame and plot them this way to all values  above some limit (1) will have one color (red).
I read documentation and im confused:

**vmin, vmax : float, optional**

*When using scalar data and no explicit norm, vmin and vmax define the data range that the colormap covers. By default, the colormap covers the complete value range of the supplied data. It is an error to use vmin/vmax when a norm instance is given (but using a str norm name together with vmin/vmax is acceptable).*

This parameter is ignored if c is RGB(A).""

My code for now:

```
points = plt.scatter(
    set1["r12_load_MW"],
    set1["dda201FrequencyHz"],
    c=set1["dda201Amplitude"],
    s=20,
    cmap="rainbow",
    alpha=1,
    vmin=0,
    vmax=1

) 
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [20.5, 10.5]


plt.title("Sensor: run2_dda2_201")
plt.xlim(-50, 420)
plt.ylim(0, 420)
plt.xlabel("r12_load_MW")
plt.ylabel("dda201FrequencyHz")
cbar = plt.colorbar(points)
cbar.set_label("dda201Amplitude")
plt.rcParams.update({"font.size": 20})
```

Does this plot shows normalized values or takes all as is? Based on plots its hard to say.

Comment: If you provide `vmin` & `vmax` values, the`c` are not normalized but the colormap is "stretched" to cover the values between `vmin` and `vmax`. You can easily confirm this yourself with random data with known distributions.

Comment: You can create a colormap and set its `over` color to red.  That way, all the values over `vmax` will be colored red.  E.g. `my_cmap = plt.get_cmap('rainbow').copy(); my_cmap.set_over('black'); plt.scatter(..., vmax=1, cmap=my_cmap)`.  With can be used as a test to make sure the coloring works as expected.  The `rainbow` colormap already uses red as the `over` color, so it works fine by default.